# Find a value, look for last column of matching value in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA. The goal is to look for the numeric value in Cell A3 of Workbook1.Sheet1. This is the search field:

[image: img]

I need to search for a match of that value in Column A of Workbook2.sheet1  then look for the last empty column of that row with the matching search value, and select it.

[image: Row A of workbook2.sheet1 may contain the value we are searching for]

I have been searching for cells.find formula that may be similar and help me get the code done, but the ones I searched only provide an already specified value.

What i am looking for is a vba code that will search for whatever value is entered in the Range("C3") of workbook1.sheet1 when you click the macro, regardless if a match exists in workbook2.sheet1 or not.

Here's the code i have so far. The cells.find is giving me a run-time error 91 with "Object variable or with block variable not set", highlighting the cells.find part.

```vb
If IsEmpty(Range("C3").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "PLEASE Enter TICKET # FIRST"
  GoTo Lastline
  Else: GoTo Search
End If

Search:
ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Select
Set wbFrom = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Downloads\Database.xlsx")


Cells.Find(What:=Selection, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).Select

Lastline:


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question to include the problematic part of the  code you have so far. This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. If you have a particular issue that you can't find an answer to online, please [edit] your post to share some background info and a **[mcve] of your code** and relevant data. More tips here: *"[ask]"* and in the [help/on-topic], as well as this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user.

Comment: thank you, @ashleedawg and Jeeped. i have edited the above query, i hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You need a button click event sub procedure within the Workbook2.sheet1's code sheet. The code sheet is accessed by right-clicking the button in Design Mode and choosing View Code.

The following is an example procedure; your own may vary depending on what you are presented with after you right-click the worksheet button.

I feel that too many people rely on range.Find when other more suitable options are available. In this case (locating a search criteria in a single column) the worksheet's Match function seems more appropriate.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If IsEmpty(Range("C3")) Then
        MsgBox "PLEASE Enter TICKET # FIRST"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim m As Variant, wbFrom As Workbook
    Set wbFrom = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Downloads\Database.xlsx")

    With wbFrom.Worksheets("sheet1")
        m = Application.Match(Range("C3").Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)

        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'there is almost always something better than .Select but that is what you asked for
            .Cells(m, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
        Else
            MsgBox "search term not found"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Please note that this code uses Range("C3").Value without parent worksheet reference. This is because it is inherited through being on a worksheet's private code sheet. Coding like this is not appropriate in a public module code sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do :

```
Sub GoTo_Ticket()

Dim WbFrom As Workbook
Dim TickNum As Range: Set TickNum = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")

If IsEmpty(TickNum) Then
    MsgBox "PLEASE Enter TICKET # FIRST"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set WbFrom = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Downloads\Database.xlsx")

Lrow = Application.Match(TickNum.Value, WbFrom.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:A"), 0)
WbFrom.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Lrow, 9999).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Please note that it is not handling situations where the ticket number is not found.

Comment: thank you, @O.PAL. though I'm getting an "Application-defined or object-defined error" on this :
'Lrow = Application.Match(TickNum.Value, WbFrom.Sheets("sheet1"), 0)'

Comment: Coded solutions should typically conform to an [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVrl.gif) environment.

Comment: @Peejay see edit : I forgot the `.Range("A:A")` for the match. Should work fine with it.

Comment: Thank you so much @O.PAL. This is working perfectly!!

Comment: Thanks. If you have the time, I would suggest having a look at @Jeeped answer which is based on the same principles but also handles "not found" tickets.

Comment: The next piece of error control would be determining whether the external workbook was already open before attempting to open it.

Comment: The next piece of error control would be determining whether the external workbook was already open before attempting to open it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things could go wrong without properly qualifying objects and variables. 
Also you actually don't need to use `Goto` here:

```
'/* declare variables */
Dim wbFrom As Workbook, r As Range, whattofind As String

If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("C3").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "PLEASE Enter TICKET # FIRST"
Else
  whattofind = Sheet1.Range("C3").Value '/* sheet1 of the current workbook */
  Set wbFrom = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Downloads\Database.xlsx")
  '/* make use of the object you set */
  With wbFrom.Sheets(1) '/* refer to Sheet1 as mentioned */
    Set r = .Range("A:A").Find(whattofind) '/* search Column A only, change to suit */
    If Not r Is Nothing Then '/* check first if something is found */
      r.End(xlToRight).Select '/* select last cell in the row
    Else
      '/* inform if nothing is found */
      Msgbox "Item not found"
    End If
  End With
End If
```

No way to test ATM, but I hope this helps.